# How to install Ariba into the Salesforce?

Tags: appexchange

I have a salesforce Developer Edition and trying to install the Ariba App using App Exchange in the Salesforce system, but I am unable to installed it.

From this site https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000004fwDqEAI, I am trying to install the Ariba App, but

[image]

I see the below error message, what's the issue ?  **How we can connect our salesforce System with Ariba SAP system ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce operates the AppExchange site and insists that applications distributed through that site have passed a Salesforce [Security Review](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Security_Review). It appears this app has not.

It is still possible to install an app that has not passed the security review simply from a URL (and typically also a password) that the vendor provides. Contact the vendor for that URL. But be aware that there will have been no check of:

> The Security Review has been developed to assess the security posture
>   of partner offerings, to ensure that applications published on the
>   AppExchange follow industry best practices for security, and to
>   promote trust.

Comment: Thanks for this info. Do you've idea how we can integrate Ariba with salesforce ?